# "Thin" sounding mic

Tags: shotgun, sennheiser, mkh, mkh415-t

I recently bought a couple used shotgun mics (MKH415t and 815t) and for some reason the 415t is very "thin" sounding. I'm wondering if it's possible the some internals got fried with improper powering. I'm running the mics through a Sound Devices 302 Mixer (which is able to supply T power) and recording to a Tascam DR-05. Any sort of input would be greatly appreciated! Below is a link to a couple clips I recorded so you could here the difference.

http://bit.ly/1RA2OwI

Comment: I don't use any of these mics - but the MKH415T definitely sound like the healthier one to me ;-) The 815T sample sounds quite boomy and muffled. Both of the mics are quite linear with a slightly rising tendency above 4KHz (which corresponds to how I hear your voice in the 415T sample)

Comment: Indeed, @MichaelHansenBuur it does sound healthier! The 815t sounds boomy probably because I was pretty close when recording, getting some proximity effect. It just sounds like there is a huge high-pass filter on the 415t, but there are no switches or anything on the mic. hmmm...